# ProcessWire install.php not removed after installation

Tags: php, installation, processwire

Processwire installer does not delete install.php and site/assets/install/. Note that ProcessWire forms warn that the installer will only delete the install files if it can.

**System**

- ubuntu 12.04
- vhost pointing to a symlink on the user file structure to source of index
- ProcessWire 5.2
- apache 2.2.22
- php 5.4

**I Tried**

- chmod 777 on the files
- chown www-data the files

I expect the installer to delete the file and folder if it says it can, since I am running a generator for the project boot, some setup can be done but not allot. The install of processwire is done manually after the generator, therefore checking deletion and handling it is not highly plausible. I am looking for any suggestions to solve the issue or a full fledged solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible for the ProcessWire Installer to delete itself, so it has to be removed manually.
However, after installing, an additional file is created to secure your installation, even if the install.php file is not deleted.

From the install.php file:

> Note that it creates this file once installation is completed:
>   /site/assets/installed.php
>   If that file exists, the installer will not run. So if you need to re-run 
>   this installer for any  reason, then you'll want to delete that file. This was 
>   implemented just in case someone doesn't delete the installer.

Comment: That would be a great answer if Ryan Cramer did not say that his mac deletes the files, https://processwire.com/talk/topic/4770-installphp-deleted-automatically/

Comment: Okay, the installation tries to remove the file if it can, but obviously it is not working in your environment. Difficult to say what the reason is.

Comment: Thanks Jasper. Ill see what I can find.